# Flash app freezes in production Flash Player 11, but works as expected in debug version

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flash

I've just stumbled upon a case when Flash app freezes in production Flash Player and works smoothly in a debug version. It doesn't throw any errors or exceptions. Has anyone ever encountered anything like this? Why is it happening or how one is supposed to debug in such case?

And a side question - what exactly is different in debug version from internal point of view? Any good writeup on the topic?

**UPDATE:**

I didn't mention, but the trouble is with Flash Player 11, it probably matters, cause Flash Player 10 doesn't have any problems with the same code.

Comment: Are you using Flash Debug player to assure no errors or exceptions are thrown in your production release build environment?

Comment: what does your app do and when does it freeze? and do i understand it right that you compile an swf that works ok in a debug player and freezes in a regular one (both of them are in the same environment, e.g. browser plugins/standalone apps)?

Comment: Do you mean, that you're debugging your swf (with breakpoints or watches)?

Comment: @www0z0k yes, that's what happens. I do not use breakpoints. I probably will, but I thought I would try to get some error or exception first in debug player. And - viola, it just works there :| Very helpful.

Comment: @Jason Sturges - in general - yes, that's what I do at some point. But in this case it was just freezing in Flash player, so I tried it in debug version. App lets users select some files and upload them. Ah... I should have mentioned probably that it's about Flash Player 11, in Flash Player 10 everything works fine.

Comment: I think FP11 stopped displaying error messages a la FP 10 and before (I'm not sure, so don't bury me if I'm wrong). Check using the debug player that there are no errors before you publish it for use with a production player

Comment: And how does it display them now? Any link to related resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone wonders here how this problem got solved.

First of all the class that was causing the hang turned out to be nifty [BitmapDataUnlimited](http://blog.formatlos.de/2008/05/28/bitmapdataunlimited/), which makes possible to overcome bitmap resolution constrain in Flash. Basically what we've changed was that we made a class directly extending EventDispatcher, rather then implementing IEventDispatcher interface and having indirect deal with private internal _eventDispatcher object.

Can anyone tell me what's the benefit of implementing IEventDispatcher interface directly?